# Set Tooltip for ListView Item in XAML WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list View for which I need tootip, I have tried

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="RelativePoint" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.VerticalOffset" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="100000" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.PlacementRectangle" Value="50,50,50,50" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=Value}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I am able to get tooltip, I wanted to know how I can apply customized tooltip with `ToolTipService`, because if my data for tooltip is large it is occupying entire screen vertically, instead I want tooltip in rectangular box

Comment: Please look this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148184/custom-tooltip-for-listbox-item-in-wpf

Comment: Make a Declarative Value for ToolT <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ToolTip" >
  <Setter.Value>
      <ContentControl ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<Setter Property="Tooltip">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Tooltip>
            <!-- whatever you want [Grid/StackPanel/etc...] -->
        </Tooltip>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that bindings are a bit ropey inside tooltips.

Comment: of course - but you always need a new target :)